# Random screenshots created and text.save files

Tags: raspbian

OS Raspbian Stretch

I keep getting random screenshots for example 2018*scrot.png and also random file.save of text files I already had made.

I only know that if I press printscreen I also get the .pngs but I am not pressing that and I do use nano for text files and sometimes close it abruptly. Could someone shed light on how I am creating these files or what is creating them so I may knock it off.

Comment: Do you want to edit a `.png` file with `nano`? That doesn't work. `nano` can only edit text files.

Comment: No, Sorry. I do not open .png files with nano.

Comment: the `text.save` files are caused by your closing it abruptly.

Comment: I now realize this should have been two questions. Thanks Pheo.